# Changing the order of colors in pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I plotted a heatmap

I want cancer to be red and healthy to be blue

```
   pheatmap(heat1, annotation_col=df,color=colorRampPalette(c("navy", "white", "red"))(50))
```

You are seeing cancer is in blue in annotation, how I can change that[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with `annotation_colors` argument :

First create a list with your conditions and then add the argument :

```
annot_colors=list(HealthStatus=c(Cancer="#F0978D",Healthy="#63D7DE"))
    
pheatmap(heat1,
         annotation_col=df,
         color=colorRampPalette(c("navy", "white", "red"))(50),
         annotation_colors=annot_colors)
```